# How to change text present on swagger authorization screen using springdoc

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

I want to change the text present on the swagger authorization UI screen.

I want to change the **Authorized** label to **Stored**.

Please find the below screenshot from swagger UI authorization screen

[image]

The reason I want to change it as it is miss leading. If the user passes an invalid credential still it is showing as authorized.

Actual validation of Username and password is happening once we execute the request.

I am also good if anyone has an answer to validate the credentials once we hit the Authorize button as shown below.

`Note: I am using Spring-boot, Spring security, and springdoc`

[image]

Any thought or ideas will be appreciated

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprindoc-openapi project relies on swagger-ui configuration properties and there is no such configuration property in this project:

- https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

You can ask the swagger-ui team, to this kind of configuration property.
If you don't want depend on their tasks priority, you can simply rebbuild the swagger-ui webjars that are available here or use the exploded mode of the webjars, where you can modify the static resources:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will look on swagger ui